# Issues converting SignaturePad bitmap to EPS

Tags: bitmap, imagemagick, xamarin.android, imagemagick-convert

I'm attempting to convert the bitmap generated by the Xamarin SignaturePad component for Android to an EPS.  It needs to be an EPS so that I can attach it to a LaTeX document (LaTeX only deals with EPS to my knowledge).

The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try
        {
            bitmap = SignaturePadView.GetImage();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace(e.StackTrace);
            Finish();
            return;
        }
        string encodedImage;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            var bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
            encodedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(bitmapData, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
        }
```

I then take that string and send it to my server backend which decodes it into a PNG.  When I do that I get what looks like a correct result, which you can see here:

[image]

If I then try to use ImageMagick to convert to an EPS like so:

```
convert myimage.png myimage.eps
```

I get an image with just a black box.  To confirm this behavior I tried converting my PNG to a JPEG like so:

```
convert myimage.png myimage.jpg
```

I get the same black box as you can see here:

[image]

If I open my decoded png in Photoshop and do a "Save As JPEG" or "Save As EPS" I get what I'm looking for.

My question at this point is... what am I doing wrong?  I've tried the same code snippet above but changed the CompressFormat to JPEG and got the same black box result.  Anyone with any experience doing this kind of image conversion able to help?

Comment: Does eps support transparent backgrounds? Probably has to do something with that.

Comment: I don't think it does... but I'm more concerned about the jpeg being a black box.  I have a jpeg2eps script I can run so if I get the jpeg correct I can get what I need.

Comment: Can you run `identify -verbose myimage.png` and post the results?

Comment: @Cheesebaron: "transparency" of backgrounds in PS, EPS and PDF is automatically there. Transparency not in the sense of there being a separate Alpha channel, as is the case with raster image formats -- more in the sense: there is no background color there ***at all*** by default; if you *want* a white opaque background, your PostScript/PDF code has to draw one first. Otherwise the white page background you normally see on screen is what the PS/PDF viewer uses in order to emulate white paper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Cheesebaron's feed back I was able to track down my problem.  There are two ways to fix this:

1.)
Change

```
bitmap = SignaturePadView.GetImage();
```

to

```
bitmap = SignaturePadView.GetImage(Color.Black, Color.White);
```

This then changes your fill color to White and thus removes the transparent background when you get the bitmap back from the signature view.

2.)
Use the alpha tag with your ImageMagick convert command to remove the transparency:

```
convert -alpha background myimage.png test.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that LaTeX can only embed EPS files for graphics or images. That aera is long gone...

If you have a reasonably recent LaTeX installation, you can use JPEG, PNG, TIFF and PDF (as well as EPS) to include pictures on your pages.

---

Anyway, to convert your PNG with ImageMagick to JPEG or EPS, try these commands:

```
 convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxcm7.png -alpha remove UXcm7.eps
 convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxcm7.png -alpha remove UXcm7.jpg
```

Comment: Kurt thank you very much for the response.  I did not know that about LaTeX as that would have saved me some grief however to stay true to the actual answer to my question of how to get a good looking EPS I'm going to mark my answer as the correct answer due to option #1 being the best choice that I found.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer adding `-alpha remove` then?!? Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: It does work however the best answer is to not even deal with the alpha and have the bitmap created with a white background.  In that case you can just use the normal convert command